# TS2451: Cannot Redeclare Block-scoped Variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, tsconfig

In a main specification (core.spec.ts) file I have the following:

```
const reqCtx = require.context('.', true, /.+\.spec\.ts$/);
reqCtx.keys().forEach(reqCtx);
module.exports = reqCtx;
```

This results in the following error:

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'reqCtx'.ts(2451)
>   core.spec.d.ts(2, 15): 'reqCtx' was also declared here.

Does anyone know how to resolve this? Configuration file *tsconfig.json* follows:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": [],
    "allowJs": false,
    "checkJs": false,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./bin",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "inlineSourceMap": false,
    "inlineSources": false
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: So that file declares two `reqCtx` bindings? Rename one of them, or don't use `const`.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I can't think of any circumstances where the line 'reqCtx.keys().forEach(reqCtx)' could possibly make sense... "call function X once for each property name in the function X"?

Comment: The idea is to `require` all the files within a (test) directory as explained [here](http://tooling.github.io/book-of-modern-frontend-tooling/dependency-management/webpack/5-require-context.html#require-context) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/9p8mrc/how_does_webpacks_requirecontext_work/).

Answer (score 0):

try first to basically run `npm ci` it works with me all the time when ESLint show this error.

However adding this option `"skipLibCheck": true` to your `compilerOptions` will disable checking